# Splitting data in r

Tags: r, split, binary, multiple-columns

I am facing the following issue.
I have a large dataset and I used `split` to make the data more approachable. I ended up with ~250 splits. As a result, each split is named as "binary code + original name". Is there a way to write the new data sets without `r` automatically adding the binary code?.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
df_NA <- data.frame(Size= c(800, 850, NA, 1200, NA),
Price =     c(900, NA, 1300, 1100, 1200),
Location =  c(NA, 'Downtown', 'Uptown', NA, 'Lakeview'),
Rooms =     c(1, 2, NA, 4, NA),
Bathrooms = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2),
Rent =      c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'No'))
```

Below I split the data (end up with three different sets), write them into my `Splits` folder, then remove the empty columns and write them in my `Updated Splits` folder.

```
# Splitting
index <- apply(is.na(df_NA)*1, 1,paste, collapse = "")
s <- split(df_NA, index)
# Writing splits into csv files and removing empty columns
for (i in 1:length(s))
{
write.csv(s[i], file = paste0("Splits/", i, "splits.csv"),
row.names=FALSE, na = "")
sdf <- data.frame(s[i])
updated_split <- sdf[,colSums(is.na(sdf))<nrow(sdf)]
write.csv(updated_split, file = paste0("Updated Splits/","updated", i, "split.csv"), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Now, when I open a random file out of the three, I get this:

```
data <- read.csv("Updated Splits/updated1split.csv")
data
  X001000.Size X001000.Price X001000.Rooms X001000.Bathrooms X001000.Rent
1          800           900             1                 1          Yes
2         1200          1100             4                 2          Yes
```

I tried `col.names=F` but it doesn't change anything. Any idea how I can go around it? Maybe there is a way to remove all of the Binary name after I write the files?

Comment: You are using a list. You need `s[[ii]]` instead of `s[ii]`.

Comment: @Pascal I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you please write an example?

Comment: @akrun I am concerned about the file itself. I just outputted it for convenience.

Comment: @Nik What is your expected output?

Comment: @akrun I want to work with the new data sets individually so I'd like the column names to be in their original state. for an example, `Size` instead of `X001000.Size`.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the problem.  Looks like @pascal's answer is what you wanted

Comment: You could set the names as NULL i.e. `s <- setNames(split(df_NA, index), NULL)` and then proceed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_NA <- data.frame(Size = c(800, 850, NA, 1200, NA),
                    Price = c(900, NA, 1300, 1100, 1200),
                    Location = c(NA, 'Downtown', 'Uptown', NA, 'Lakeview'),
                    Rooms = c(1, 2, NA, 4, NA),
                    Bathrooms = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2),
                    Rent = c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'No'))

index <- apply(is.na(df_NA)*1, 1,paste, collapse = "")
s <- split(df_NA, index)
i <- 1

# subset using [i] 
sdf <- data.frame(s[i])
updated_split <- sdf[,colSums(is.na(sdf))<nrow(sdf)]
updated_split 
#   X001000.Size X001000.Price X001000.Rooms X001000.Bathrooms X001000.Rent
# 1          800           900             1                 1          Yes
# 4         1200          1100             4                 2          Yes

# subset using [[i]]
sdf <- data.frame(s[[i]])
updated_split <- sdf[,colSums(is.na(sdf))<nrow(sdf)]
updated_split
#   Size Price Rooms Bathrooms Rent
# 1  800   900     1         1  Yes
# 4 1200  1100     4         2  Yes
```